# list with a expandable image background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

im new developing in html and css and im having a problem trying to achieve a list with a background image that adapt to the quantity of elements that the list have and change its height respect to the list items.
I share an example here, the idea is to set the list below "Menu" and 
the rest of the image change respect the elements in the list.
Thanks.

```html
<ul>
  <img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1695098/1207/i/950/depositphotos_12070017-stock-photo-menu-background.jpg">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why are you not using a `background-image`? If the "borders" are fixed (ie. you don't want them stretched), use a `border-image` too. You can't just slap an `<img>` in there and hope for the best...

Comment: To start with it's **invalid HTML**.

Answer (score 2):

your html markup is invalid, a `ul` can only contain as direct children the `li` element.

Then to achieve what you want you need to set `background-image` in `ul`

```css
ul {
  background-image: url(https://st.depositphotos.com/1695098/1207/i/950/depositphotos_12070017-stock-photo-menu-background.jpg)
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that, in order to achieve the result you're looking for, you will want to place both the image and the  inside a div with a position of relative. Then make the image the main element that defines the size of the div and position the  absolutely where you want it.

Observe the code below. You will likely want to run it in full-page mode. It will center the text and the image. The top property on the menu class will dictate how far from the top your text is.

```css
.menuContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.menuContainer img {
 width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuContainer">
  <img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1695098/1207/i/950/depositphotos_12070017-stock-photo-menu-background.jpg">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>Steak</li>
    <li>Chicken</li>
    <li>Macaroni and Cheese</li>
    <li>Mashed Potatoes</li>
    <li>Chocolate Mousse</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget the style tags:

```
<style>
ul {
background-image: url(https://st.depositphotos.com/1695098/1207/i/950/depositphotos_12070017-stock-photo-menu-background.jpg)
}
</style>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```